# Show IVP solution exactness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that solution of $ y' = sin(ty)$, $y(0)=0$ is exact in $0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{2}$?

I tried to substitute $ty$ with a new variable, but it doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: ??? What does it _mean_ to say the solution is "exact"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Picard-Lindelöf, the IVP

$y'(t)= \sin (ty(t)), \quad y(0)=0$

has a unique solution.

$y(t)=0$ is a solution of the IVP.

Conclusion ?

Answer (score 1):

Let
Observe that
$$
|y'(t)|=|\sin (ty(t))|\le t|y(t)|
$$
for all $t\ge 0$. Set
$$
z(t)=\int_0^t |y'(s)|\,ds\ge 0,
$$
and thus
$$
z'(t)=|y'(t)|\le t|y(t)|=t\left|\int_0^t y'(s)\,ds\,\right|\le t\int_0^t|y'(s)|\,ds=tz(t).
$$
Hence $z'\le tz$ and thus
$$
\big(\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}z(t)\big)'=\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\big(z'(t)-tz(t)\big)\le 0,
$$
and integrating in $[0,t]$ we obtain
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}z(t)-\mathrm{e}^{0}z(0)\le 0
$$
or $z(t)\le 0$, for all $t\ge 0$. Thus $z'(t)=|y'(t)|\equiv 0$, and hence $y\equiv 0$.