# Show IVP solution exactness in given interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that solution of $ y' = e^{-t^2}+y^2$, $y(0)=0$ is exact in $0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: You just asked the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809915/show-ivp-solution-exactness) with a different equation moments ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean *existence* - not exactness. In any case, you have a Riccati equation, which is linearlized by the change of variable
$$y=-\frac{u'}{u}, \tag{1} $$
into 
$$u''=-\mathrm{e}^{-t^2} u.$$
The initial conditions are transformed into
$$u(0)=1,u'(0)=0.$$
(In fact, the scaling symmetry of $(1)$ allows you to take any nonzero value for  $u(0)$.)

Singularities will arise in $y$ precisely when $u=0$. Suppose we restrict ourselves to a time interval $t \in [0,T]$, in which $u$ is positive. We then have the following differential inequality over that interval
$$u''  \geq -u ,$$
and the theory of linear differential inequalities implies that upon integration,
$$u(t) \geq \cos(t). $$

Hence $u$ is positive at least in the interval $[0,\pi/2)$, and correspondingly, $y$ is smooth there.